# How to find most commonly occurring non-unique keys in Boost MultiIndex?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-multi-index

Boost MultiIndex Container, when defined to have `hashed_non_unique` keys, can group equivalent keys together and return them all against an `equal_range` query, as mentioned [here](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_0/libs/multi_index/doc/tutorial/indices.html#hash_unique_non_unique). But I see no way of querying the largest range (or n largest ranges) in a set. Without comparing between the range sizes of distinct hashes, which can become computationally very expensive, is there a way to query the largest equal ranges?

If we consider a simple example, such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30977335/1062484), I would like to query by frequency and get `Tom` as the first result, and then `Jack` and `Leo` in no particular order.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, if you're using non-unique hashed indices, turns out `equal_range` does **not** invoke equality comparison for all the elements in the returned range (unlike common implementations of `std::unordered_multimap`, BTW), so the following can be very efficient:

```
template<typename HashIndex>
std::multimap<
  std::size_t,
  std::reference_wrapper<const typename HashIndex::value_type>,
  std::greater<std::size_t>
> group_sizes(const HashIndex& i)
{
  decltype(group_sizes(i)) res;
  for(auto it=i.begin(),end=i.end();it!=end;){
    auto next=i.equal_range(*it).second;
    res.emplace((std::size_t)std::distance(it,next),*it);
    it=next;
  }
  return res;
}
```

To check how efficient this actually is, let's try instrumenting the element type:

**<kbd>[Live Coliru Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/fe3b5df0e4b194be)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/multi_index_container.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index/hashed_index.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index/identity.hpp>
#include <cstring>
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <tuple>
#include <map>

template<typename HashIndex>
std::multimap<
  std::size_t,
  std::reference_wrapper<const typename HashIndex::value_type>,
  std::greater<std::size_t>
> group_sizes(const HashIndex& i)
{
  decltype(group_sizes(i)) res;
  for(auto it=i.begin(),end=i.end();it!=end;){
    auto next=i.equal_range(*it).second;
    res.emplace((std::size_t)std::distance(it,next),*it);
    it=next;
  }
  return res;
}

struct instrumented_string:std::string
{
  using std::string::string;
  
  static void reset_nums()
  {
    num_hashes=0;
    num_eqs=0;
  }
  
  static std::size_t num_hashes,num_eqs;
};

std::size_t instrumented_string::num_hashes=0;
std::size_t instrumented_string::num_eqs=0;

bool operator==(const instrumented_string& x,const instrumented_string& y)
{
  ++instrumented_string::num_eqs;
  return static_cast<std::string>(x)==y;
}

std::size_t hash_value(const instrumented_string& x)
{
  ++instrumented_string::num_hashes;
  return boost::hash<std::string>{}(x);
}

using namespace boost::multi_index;
using container=multi_index_container<
  instrumented_string,
  indexed_by<
    hashed_non_unique<identity<instrumented_string>>
  >
>;

int main()
{
  auto values={"Tom","Jack","Leo","Bjarne","Subhamoy"};
  container c;
  for(auto& v:values){
    for(auto i=100*std::strlen(v);i--;)c.insert(v);
  }
  
  instrumented_string::reset_nums();
  
  auto gs=group_sizes(c);
  for(const auto& g:gs){
    std::cout<<g.first<<": "<<g.second.get()<<"\n";
  }
  
  std::cout<<"# hashes: "<<instrumented_string::num_hashes<<"\n";
  std::cout<<"# eqs: "<<instrumented_string::num_eqs<<"\n";
}
```

**Output**

```
800: Subhamoy
600: Bjarne
400: Jack
300: Tom
300: Leo
# hashes: 5
# eqs: 5
```

So, for a container with 2,400 elements, invoking `group_sizes` has resulted in just 5 hash calculations and 5 equality comparisons (plus ~2,400 iterator increments, of course).

If you really want to get rid of hashes, the following can do:

**<kbd>[Live Coliru Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ec9f9fe95695a93e)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/multi_index_container.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index/hashed_index.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index/identity.hpp>
#include <cstring>
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <string>
#include <map>

template<typename HashIndex>
struct internal_reference
{
  const HashIndex&                      i;
  const typename HashIndex::value_type& r;
  std::size_t                           buc;
};

template<typename HashIndex>
struct internal_reference_equal_to
{
  bool operator()(
    const typename HashIndex::value_type& x,
    const internal_reference<HashIndex>& y)const
  {
    return
      std::addressof(x)==std::addressof(y.r)||
      y.i.key_eq()(y.i.key_extractor()(x),y.i.key_extractor()(y.r));
  }

  bool operator()(
    const internal_reference<HashIndex>& x,
    const typename HashIndex::value_type& y)const
  {
    return (*this)(y,x);
  }
};

template<typename HashIndex>
struct internal_reference_hash
{
  std::size_t operator()(const internal_reference<HashIndex>& x)const
  {
    return x.buc;
  }
};

template<typename HashIndex>
std::multimap<
  std::size_t,
  std::reference_wrapper<const typename HashIndex::value_type>,
  std::greater<std::size_t>
> group_sizes(const HashIndex& i)
{
  decltype(group_sizes(i)) res;
  for(std::size_t buc=0,buc_count=i.bucket_count();buc<buc_count;++buc){
    for(auto it=i.begin(buc),end=i.end(buc);it!=end;){
      auto        p=i.equal_range(
                      internal_reference<HashIndex>{i,*it,buc},
                      internal_reference_hash<HashIndex>{},
                      internal_reference_equal_to<HashIndex>{});
      std::size_t dist=0;
      auto        next=it;
      while(p.first!=p.second){
        ++p.first;
        ++dist;
        ++next;
      }
      res.emplace(dist,*it);
      it=next;
    }
  }
  return res;
}

struct instrumented_string:std::string
{
  using std::string::string;
  
  static void reset_nums()
  {
    num_hashes=0;
    num_eqs=0;
  }
  
  static std::size_t num_hashes,num_eqs;
};

std::size_t instrumented_string::num_hashes=0;
std::size_t instrumented_string::num_eqs=0;

bool operator==(const instrumented_string& x,const instrumented_string& y)
{
  ++instrumented_string::num_eqs;
  return static_cast<std::string>(x)==y;
}

std::size_t hash_value(const instrumented_string& x)
{
  ++instrumented_string::num_hashes;
  return boost::hash<std::string>{}(x);
}

using namespace boost::multi_index;
using container=multi_index_container<
  instrumented_string,
  indexed_by<
    hashed_non_unique<identity<instrumented_string>>
  >
>;

int main()
{
  auto values={"Tom","Jack","Leo","Bjarne","Subhamoy"};
  container c;
  for(auto& v:values){
    for(auto i=100*std::strlen(v);i--;)c.insert(v);
  }
  
  instrumented_string::reset_nums();
  
  auto gs=group_sizes(c);
  for(const auto& g:gs){
    std::cout<<g.first<<": "<<g.second.get()<<"\n";
  }
  
  std::cout<<"# hashes: "<<instrumented_string::num_hashes<<"\n";
  std::cout<<"# eqs: "<<instrumented_string::num_eqs<<"\n";
}
```

**Output**

```
800: Subhamoy
600: Bjarne
400: Jack
300: Tom
300: Leo
# hashes: 0
# eqs: 0
```

But please bear in mind this version of `group_sizes` exploits the **undocumented** fact that elements with hash value `h` get placed in the bucket `h%bucket_count()` (or, put another way, `internal_reference<HashIndex>` hashing is technically not a conformant [*compatible extension*](https://www.boost.org/libs/multi_index/doc/reference/hash_indices.html#lookup) of the index hash function).

Answer (score 2):

It seems like you might be metter served with a `std::map<K, std::vector<V> >` like interface here.

You would still always have to do the counting.

> To have the counting done "magically" you might consider making the "bucket key" a refcounting type.
>
> This would be more magical than I'd be comfortable with for my code-bases. In particular, copied elements could easily cause overcounting.

### Approach 1: BMI + RangeV3 for syntactic sugar

Warning: I consider this "advanced", as in the learning curve might be steepish. However, when you wield Ranges with ease, this can become a great productivity boost.

Note also, this does not in any way promise to increase performance. But you should note that no elements are copied, the vector (`groups`)  merely contains subranges, which are iterator ranges into the multi-index container.

**[Live On Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/q6xxz8)**

```
#include <boost/multi_index/composite_key.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index/member.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index/ordered_index.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index_container.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <range/v3/all.hpp>
#include <fmt/ranges.h>
#include <fmt/ostream.h>

namespace bmi = boost::multi_index;
namespace vw  = ranges::views;
namespace act = ranges::actions;

struct Person {
    int m_id;
    std::string m_name;

    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, Person const& p) {
        return os << "[" << p.m_id << ", " << std::quoted(p.m_name) << "]";
    }
};

typedef bmi::multi_index_container<
    Person,
    bmi::indexed_by<
        bmi::ordered_unique<bmi::member<Person, int, &Person::m_id>>,
        bmi::ordered_unique<
            bmi::tag<struct by_name_id>,
            bmi::composite_key<Person,
                bmi::member<Person, std::string, &Person::m_name>,
                bmi::member<Person, int, &Person::m_id>>
        >
    > >
    Roster;

template <typename Index, typename KeyExtractor>
std::size_t distinct(const Index& i, KeyExtractor key) {
    std::size_t res = 0;
    for (auto it = i.begin(), it_end = i.end(); it != it_end;) {
        ++res;
        it = i.upper_bound(key(*it));
    }
    return res;
}

int main() {
    Roster const r {
        {1, "Tom"},
        {2, "Jack"},
        {3, "Tom"},
        {4, "Leo"}
    };
    fmt::print("Roster: {}\n", r);

    static constexpr auto eq_   = std::equal_to<>{};
    static constexpr auto name_ = std::mem_fn(&Person::m_name);
    static constexpr auto size_ = [](auto const& r) constexpr { return std::distance(begin(r), end(r)); };
    auto& idx = r.get<by_name_id>();
    fmt::print("Distinct: {}, Index: {}\n", distinct(idx, name_), idx);

    auto by_name_ = vw::group_by([](auto const&... arg) { return eq_(name_(arg)...); });
    auto by_size_ = [](auto const&... subrange) { return (size_(subrange) > ...); };

    auto groups = idx | by_name_ | ranges::to_vector;

    for (auto&& x : groups |= act::sort(by_size_)) {
        fmt::print("#{} persons in group {}: {}\n",
                size_(x),
                name_(ranges::front(x)),
                x);
    }
}
```

Prints:

```
Roster: {[1, "Tom"], [2, "Jack"], [3, "Tom"], [4, "Leo"]}
Distinct: 3, Index: {[2, "Jack"], [4, "Leo"], [1, "Tom"], [3, "Tom"]}
#2 persons in group Tom: {[1, "Tom"], [3, "Tom"]}
#1 persons in group Jack: {[2, "Jack"]}
#1 persons in group Leo: {[4, "Leo"]}
```

Note, I merely kept the `distinct()` function from the [original link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30977335/1062484). You could [drop it](https://godbolt.org/z/fb9TrK) to remove some noise.

### Approach 2: The same, but w/o Boost

Multi-index seems to be supplying nothing more than the ordered container now, so let's simplify:

**[Live On Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/4Ecd7E)**

```
#include <set>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <range/v3/all.hpp>
#include <fmt/ranges.h>
#include <fmt/ostream.h>

namespace vw  = ranges::views;
namespace act = ranges::actions;

struct Person {
    int m_id;
    std::string m_name;

    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, Person const& p) {
        return os << "[" << p.m_id << ", " << std::quoted(p.m_name) << "]";
    }

    bool operator<(Person const& o) const { return m_name < o.m_name; }
};

int main() {
    std::multiset<Person> const r {
        {1, "Tom"},
        {2, "Jack"},
        {3, "Tom"},
        {4, "Leo"}
    };
    fmt::print("Roster: {}\n", r);

    static constexpr auto eq_   = std::equal_to<>{};
    static constexpr auto name_ = std::mem_fn(&Person::m_name);
    static constexpr auto size_ = [](auto const& r) constexpr { return std::distance(begin(r), end(r)); };
    auto by_name_ = vw::group_by([](auto const&... arg) { return eq_(name_(arg)...); });
    auto by_size_ = [](auto const&... subrange) { return (size_(subrange) > ...); };

    auto groups = r | by_name_ | ranges::to_vector;

    for (auto&& x : groups |= act::sort(by_size_)) {
        fmt::print("#{} persons in group {}: {}\n",
                size_(x),
                name_(ranges::front(x)),
                x);
    }
}
```

Prints

```
Roster: {[2, "Jack"], [4, "Leo"], [1, "Tom"], [3, "Tom"]}
#2 persons in group Tom: {[1, "Tom"], [3, "Tom"]}
#1 persons in group Jack: {[2, "Jack"]}
#1 persons in group Leo: {[4, "Leo"]}
```

> Bonus: Slightly more simplified assuming equality operator on Person suffices: https://godbolt.org/z/58xsTK