# Equivalent of GROUP BY COUNT using boost multi-index

Tags: c++, group-by, boost-multi-index

I'm using `boost::multi_index_container` to perform some operations on satellite data.

I have a data structure that looks like this:

```
struct SatData {
  std::string sat_system;
  std::string band;
  int index;
  uint64_t time;
  double data;

  SatData(const std::string& ss,
          const std::string& b,
          const int& i,
          const uint64_t& t,
          const double& d) : sat_system(ss), band(b), index(i), time(t), data(d) {}
};


using SatDataset =
multi_index_container <SatData, indexed_by
                        <                          
                          ordered_unique // given a specific satellite and a time, the measurement is unique
                          <
                            composite_key
                            <
                              SatData,
                              member<SatData, std::string, &SatData::sat_system>,
                              member<SatData, std::string, &SatData::band>,
                              member<SatData, int, &SatData::index>,
                              member<SatData, uint64_t, &SatData::time>
                            > // composite key
                          > // ordered_not_unique
                      
                        > // indexed_by
                      >; // multi_index_container
```

I would like to retrieve, for each sat_system+band+index, the number of measurements, so for example, if I had a table like this:

```
GPS     | L1  | 1 | 10
GPS     | L1  | 1 | 11
GPS     | L1  | 1 | 12
GPS     | L2  | 1 | 10
GPS     | L2  | 1 | 11
GPS     | L2  | 1 | 12
GPS     | L2  | 4 | 11
GPS     | L2  | 4 | 12
GALILEO | E5b | 2 | 10
GLONASS | G1  | 1 | 10
GLONASS | G1  | 1 | 11
GLONASS | G1  | 2 | 10
```

the answer would be:

```
GPS     | L1  | 1 | 3
GPS     | L2  | 1 | 2
GPS     | L2  | 1 | 1
GPS     | L2  | 4 | 2
GALILEO | E5b | 2 | 1
GLONASS | G1  | 1 | 3
```

I'm a bit rusty but I think a pseudo-SQL equivalent would be something like:

```
SELECT sat_stystem, band, index, COUNT(time)
GROUP_BY sat_stystem, band, index
```

I have found this related question:
[How to get the distinct count of first key in boost::multi_index_container with composite key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30975769/how-to-get-the-distinct-count-of-first-key-in-boostmulti-index-container-with/30977335#30977335)

but it is specific for one search query, while I would like to have a result for the whole table instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no prefab functionality for that, but you can basically do it yourself the same way a SQL planner would do internally:

**<kbd>[Live Coliru Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/548700ffd9576186)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/multi_index_container.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index/composite_key.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index/member.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index/ordered_index.hpp>
#include <string>

using namespace boost::multi_index;

struct SatData {
    std::string sat_system;
    std::string band;
    int index;
    uint64_t time;
    double data;
    
    SatData(
        const std::string& ss,
        const std::string& b,
        const int& i,
        const uint64_t& t,
        const double& d) : 
        sat_system(ss), band(b), index(i), time(t), data(d) {}
};


using SatDataset =
multi_index_container<
    SatData, indexed_by<                          
        ordered_unique< // given a specific satellite and a time, the measurement is unique
            composite_key<
                SatData,
                member<SatData, std::string, &SatData::sat_system>,
                member<SatData, std::string, &SatData::band>,
                member<SatData, int, &SatData::index>,
                member<SatData, uint64_t, &SatData::time>
            > // composite key
        > // ordered_not_unique
    > // indexed_by
>; // multi_index_container

#include <iostream>
                      
int main()
{
  SatDataset s = {
    {"GPS"     , "L1"  , 1 , 10, 0.112},
    {"GPS"     , "L1"  , 1 , 11, 0.201},
    {"GPS"     , "L1"  , 1 , 12, 0.100},
    {"GPS"     , "L2"  , 1 , 10, 0.098},
    {"GPS"     , "L2"  , 1 , 11, 0.134},
    {"GPS"     , "L2"  , 1 , 12, 0.167},
    {"GPS"     , "L2"  , 4 , 11, 0.199},
    {"GPS"     , "L2"  , 4 , 12, 0.204},
    {"GALILEO" , "E5b" , 2 , 10, 0.056},
    {"GLONASS" , "G1"  , 1 , 10, 0.123},
    {"GLONASS" , "G1"  , 1 , 11, 0.222},
    {"GLONASS" , "G1"  , 2 , 10, 0.115},
  };
  
  for(auto first = s.begin(), last = s.end(); first != last; ) {
    auto next = s.upper_bound(std::make_tuple(
        first->sat_system,
        first->band,
        first->index));
    std::cout
        << first->sat_system << "\t|"
        << first->band << "\t|"
        << first->index << "\t|"
        << std::distance(first, next) << "\n";
    first = next;
  }
}
```

**Output**

```
GALILEO |E5b |2 |1
GLONASS |G1  |1 |2
GLONASS |G1  |2 |1
GPS     |L1  |1 |3
GPS     |L2  |1 |3
GPS     |L2  |4 |2
```

Also, if you're going to do many of these operations, considering using [ranked indices](https://www.boost.org/libs/multi_index/doc/tutorial/indices.html#rnk_indices):

**<kbd>[Live Coliru Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/bfcec3bcec6922a9)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/multi_index_container.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index/composite_key.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index/member.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index/ranked_index.hpp>
#include <string>

using namespace boost::multi_index;

struct SatData {
    std::string sat_system;
    std::string band;
    int index;
    uint64_t time;
    double data;
    
    SatData(
        const std::string& ss,
        const std::string& b,
        const int& i,
        const uint64_t& t,
        const double& d) : 
        sat_system(ss), band(b), index(i), time(t), data(d) {}
};


using SatDataset =
multi_index_container<
    SatData, indexed_by<                          
        ranked_unique< // given a specific satellite and a time, the measurement is unique
            composite_key<
                SatData,
                member<SatData, std::string, &SatData::sat_system>,
                member<SatData, std::string, &SatData::band>,
                member<SatData, int, &SatData::index>,
                member<SatData, uint64_t, &SatData::time>
            > // composite key
        > // ordered_not_unique
    > // indexed_by
>; // multi_index_container

#include <iostream>
                      
int main()
{
  SatDataset s = {
    {"GPS"     , "L1"  , 1 , 10, 0.112},
    {"GPS"     , "L1"  , 1 , 11, 0.201},
    {"GPS"     , "L1"  , 1 , 12, 0.100},
    {"GPS"     , "L2"  , 1 , 10, 0.098},
    {"GPS"     , "L2"  , 1 , 11, 0.134},
    {"GPS"     , "L2"  , 1 , 12, 0.167},
    {"GPS"     , "L2"  , 4 , 11, 0.199},
    {"GPS"     , "L2"  , 4 , 12, 0.204},
    {"GALILEO" , "E5b" , 2 , 10, 0.056},
    {"GLONASS" , "G1"  , 1 , 10, 0.123},
    {"GLONASS" , "G1"  , 1 , 11, 0.222},
    {"GLONASS" , "G1"  , 2 , 10, 0.115},
  };
  
  std::size_t rank_first = 0;  
  for(auto first = s.begin(), last = s.end(); first != last; ) {
    auto rank_next = s.upper_bound_rank(std::make_tuple(
        first->sat_system,
        first->band,
        first->index));
    std::cout
        << first->sat_system << "\t|"
        << first->band << "\t|"
        << first->index << "\t|"
        << rank_next - rank_first << "\n";
    rank_first = rank_next;
    first = s.nth(rank_first);
  }
}
```

You need to measure in order to know which approach is faster, but in principle ranked indices will get the group sizes (`rank_next - rank_first`) in logarithmic time, whereas ordered indices are linear on the number of elements in each group.

**Updated Aug 30**

As per the OP's additional question, getting other calculated values, such as measurement averaging, is straightworfward once we have the range on which to do the calculation:

**<kbd>[Live Coliru Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/bd98628f7d3ea648)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/multi_index_container.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index/composite_key.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index/member.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index/ordered_index.hpp>
#include <string>

using namespace boost::multi_index;

struct SatData {
    std::string sat_system;
    std::string band;
    int index;
    uint64_t time;
    double data;
    
    SatData(
        const std::string& ss,
        const std::string& b,
        const int& i,
        const uint64_t& t,
        const double& d) : 
        sat_system(ss), band(b), index(i), time(t), data(d) {}
};


using SatDataset =
multi_index_container<
    SatData, indexed_by<                          
        ordered_unique< // given a specific satellite and a time, the measurement is unique
            composite_key<
                SatData,
                member<SatData, std::string, &SatData::sat_system>,
                member<SatData, std::string, &SatData::band>,
                member<SatData, int, &SatData::index>,
                member<SatData, uint64_t, &SatData::time>
            > // composite key
        > // ordered_not_unique
    > // indexed_by
>; // multi_index_container

#include <iostream>
#include <numeric>
                      
int main()
{
  SatDataset s = {
    {"GPS"     , "L1"  , 1 , 10, 0.112},
    {"GPS"     , "L1"  , 1 , 11, 0.201},
    {"GPS"     , "L1"  , 1 , 12, 0.100},
    {"GPS"     , "L2"  , 1 , 10, 0.098},
    {"GPS"     , "L2"  , 1 , 11, 0.134},
    {"GPS"     , "L2"  , 1 , 12, 0.167},
    {"GPS"     , "L2"  , 4 , 11, 0.199},
    {"GPS"     , "L2"  , 4 , 12, 0.204},
    {"GALILEO" , "E5b" , 2 , 10, 0.056},
    {"GLONASS" , "G1"  , 1 , 10, 0.123},
    {"GLONASS" , "G1"  , 1 , 11, 0.222},
    {"GLONASS" , "G1"  , 2 , 10, 0.115},
  };
  
  for(auto first = s.begin(), last = s.end(); first != last; ) {
    auto next = s.upper_bound(std::make_tuple(
        first->sat_system,
        first->band,
        first->index));
    auto dist = std::distance(first, next);
    auto mean = std::accumulate(
        first, next, 0.0,
        [](double acc, const SatData& x) { return acc + x.data; }) / dist;
    std::cout
        << first->sat_system << "\t|"
        << first->band << "\t|"
        << first->index << "\t|"
        << dist << "\t|"
        << mean << "\n";
    first = next;
  }
}
```

**Output**

```
GALILEO |E5b    |2  |1  |0.056
GLONASS |G1     |1  |2  |0.1725
GLONASS |G1     |2  |1  |0.115
GPS     |L1     |1  |3  |0.137667
GPS     |L2     |1  |3  |0.133
GPS     |L2     |4  |2  |0.2015
```

Comment: Cool, that's really helpful. 

What about other grouping operations such as AVG() ? Would I use `find_range` and apply a function to each with some boost magic?

Comment: updated answer.